# How to toggle between the 2 icons in same div when the icon is clicked

Tags: angular

I want to achieve the functionality in **angular2** similar to what happen when any mail is Starred. Ex :- when I click on the empty star icon it goes and check via some service calls, if the result is true then display a new icon with filled star icon in the same div tag in `HTML`.

```
<div class="star-result" >
<img src="./images/star_unfilled.png" id="star-result" (click)="isStarred()" alt="Star this result">&nbsp;{{RowName}}
</div>
```

Can someone help with this toggling part on the click event i.e on click the icon should change based on the response ??

Comment: <div class="star-result" >
<img src="./images/star_unfilled.png" id="star-result" (click)="isStarred()" alt="Star this result">&nbsp;{{RowName}}
</div>

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show and ng-hide to do this

```html
<div data-ng-show=(true)> <img/> </div>
<div data-ng-show=(false)> <img/> </div>
```

or in your case

```html
<div class="star-result" data-ng-click="selected!=selected"> 
  <img data-ng-show="selected"  src="./images/star_unfilled.png" id="star-result"  alt="Star this result"/>
  <img data-ng-hide="selected"  src="./images/star_filled.png" id="star-result"  alt="Star this result"/>
  {{RowName}} 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a property that stores whether an item is already starred or not and bind to that in order to show either one or the other image. Then use another function in the click handler of the unstarred icon that makes the request to star it and updates the property.

```
<img *ngIf="!isStarred" src="./images/star_unfilled.png" id="star-result" (click)="star()" alt="Star this result">
<img *ngIf="isStarred" src="./images/star_filled.png" id="star-result" (click)="unstar()" alt="Unstar this result">
```

And in the viewmodel you have something like:

```
isStarred: boolean = false;

star() {
    // Do whatever it takes to star something
    // And at the end update local status 
    isStarred = true;
}

unstar() {
    // Do whatever it takes to star something
    // And at the end update local status 
    isStarred = false;
}
```

You could optionally also use a single `img` element and bind the src property depending on the `isStarred` value. And instead of star() and unstar() methods use a single `toggleStar()` method. Dozens of options here.